# Output Assertion Results Using Gatling

Tags: report, assertions, gatling

I have been working on Gatling to set up performance tests for REST services and have assertions setup but they do not output the result in the Reports.

Have the below setup in the scala file.

```
val scn = scenario(scenarioName)
          .during(testTimeSecs) {
            exec(
              http(requestName)
                .post(URI)              
                .headers(http_headers)
                .body(ElFileBody(System.getProperty("xmlFile"))).asXML
                .check(status.is(200))          
            )
            .pause(minWaitMs, maxWaitMs)
          }
        setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(noOfUsers) over (rampUpTimeSecs seconds))).protocols(httpConf).assertions(global.responseTime.max.lessThan(100))
```

I seem to obviously miss something, nothing helps in outputting the assertions in the reports. Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, assertion results are not currently displayed in the HTML reports. They only are in the JUnit file and trigger the returned code.

Comment: Is it the assertions file generated in the js folder? That file has the assertions empty as well, {
  "simulation": "basic.PostRequestTestSimulation",
  "simulationId": "postrequesttestsimulation",
  "start": 1467230891199,
  "description": "",
  "scenarios": ["test_post-scenario"],
  "assertions": [

  ]
}

Comment: do not see any thing in the JSON file above or the JUnit file <?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuite time="0" failures="0" errors="0" tests="0" name="basic.PostRequestTestSimulation"> </testsuite>